# Why am I able to select the items of a listview only from the emulator and not on my real device?

Tags: android

I have this big problem that is making me desperate. I can't understand why on my real device (with Android 10) the listview items are not selected while on the android studio emulator I can select them without problems. I tried to add a print when an item is selected and this print is showed in the log. How is this possible? The SDK used is 30 and the Android version on the emulator is 7. Can someone help me? I'm really desperate. Thanks in advance. If necessary I can add my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".activities.AudioToSendActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="552dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="800dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/audio_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/current"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:text="00:00"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekbar"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:theme="@style/SeekBar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:text="00:00"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/prev"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_previous_black_24dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_play_circle_filled_black_24dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_next_black_24dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Audio> audioArrayList;
    public OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public AudioAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Audio> audioArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.audioArrayList = audioArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public AudioAdapter.viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.audio_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AudioAdapter.viewHolder holder, final int i) {
        holder.title.setText(audioArrayList.get(i).getAudioTitle());
        holder.artist.setText(audioArrayList.get(i).getAudioArtist());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return audioArrayList.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title, artist;

        public viewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_title);
            artist = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_artist);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int pos, View v);
    }
```

Comment: Add your listview code

Comment: I've edited my question, thank you

Comment: Can you add the code related to onClickListener...

Comment: Yes, I added that

Comment: ` If necessary I can add my code` it's always necessary :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes it's necessary but having no errors in the Log I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: You are using an interface for onClick then why are you not passing in the constructor of AudioAdapter. Implement that interface in the activtiy that is using AudioAdapter class.

Comment: @MrudulTora I've tried to implement the interface and the onItemClick method in the activity that use AudioAdapter class but it doesn't work. I forgot to mention that if I run code individually it works, but in my app it doesn't. Could it be due to some dependencies in the gradle file?

Comment: It's weird. Try cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: @MrudulTora I've tried countless times but it doesn't work. I followed this guide if it helps: https://www.11zon.com/zon/android/how-to-play-audio-with-seekbar-in-android.php If I run this code, it works but if I add it in my app it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I've solved. The problem is in the gradle file.